# <jsp:include tag doesnt work <jsp:include page="Remote.jsp"/>

Tags: jsp, tags, include

Remote.jsp code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Remote Value</title>
</head>
<body>
<% 
     File remote = new File("D:\\test.txt");
     FileReader fr = new FileReader(remote);
     int ch;
     while((ch = fr.read()) != -1)
       out.println("<p>" + (char)ch + "</p>");
     fr.close();
  %>
</body>
</html>
```

`<jsp:include page="Remote.jsp"/>` is embedded into another jsp and the path is correct.
But everytime I get an exception.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 11 in the jsp file: /Remote.jsp File cannot be resolved to a type
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this exception when `Remote.jsp` has failed to compile by itself. You can test it by opening the file directly without including it in another page. You would then see clear exceptions about the cause. As far as I see you're missing at least the `java.io.*` import in the `Remote.jsp`.

```
<%@page import="java.io.*" %>
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, this is a poor approach. It not only potentially results in syntactically invalid HTML in the other JSP (you cannot nest `<html>` and so on). Consider using a servlet which reads the file from disk and streams it to the response. Then you can just do

```
<div style="white-space: pre;">
    <jsp:include page="fileservlet/test.txt" />
</div>
```